# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in Visual Studio not debuggable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have been working with an ASP.NET Core 6 ASP.NET Web API project for months... always able to set and use break points in controller actions. Suddenly yesterday the break points are now ignored. Why?

My settings:

- I am in the Debug configuration (as usual).
- I don't believe I need to configure a symbol server (never needed it before), but I decided to configure "Microsoft Symbol Servers" just to be sure.
- I turned on "Enable native code debugging", even though this is C# and not C++ and I've not needed this before, because another SO post suggested it.

The best I can figure of what caused this...is that I enabled "javascript debugging" yesterday. Perhaps that somehow de-activated C# debugging? I went back into my configuration settings and turned it back off again... but C# still won't hit break points.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? If yes, check which is the active one.

Comment: try to remove bin/ object/ folder and rebuild the project then run

Comment: @NineBerry The correct active project is selected.  The program runs exactly as expected...just no debugging capability.

Comment: @ZiedR. I manually deleted all `bin` and `obj` folders from all projects...and did a rebuild.  The problem continues.